# Continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: real-analysis

I have a question.

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and let $L \in \mathbb{R}^m$. Show that

$\lim_{x \to c}f(x) = L$ if and only if $\lim_{x \to c} \| f(x) - L\| =0$.

How can I proof this?

Thank you

Comment: Break it into pieces since it is a vector-to-vector mapping. Then you can use triangle inequality to work the limit.

Comment: If you remember the ‘epsilon-delta’ ($\epsilon$-$\delta$) definition of the limit, the result is obvious. Think: how could you prove the same for a one-variable real function?